# Cakephp3 integrate framework css

Tags: cakephp, dml

Good afternoon , I am a rookie and I have a doubt. As I can integrate another CSS framework also boostrap? 
I have been reading the documentation The App View but do not understand well

I want to use MDL but I have no idea how
Help?

Comment: By default it uses Foundation. But of course you can use anything else, for example Bootstrap. For that there is a whole plugin in the templating section: https://github.com/FriendsOfCake/awesome-cakephp#templating

Comment: hi, thanks for answering . I have already tried the plugin FriendsOfCake , but now , I need to use another framework.what files I Should edit to use another framework? like  Material Design Lite

Comment: Views are just pieces of (most of the time) HTML that get glued together. In Cake they're called *.ctp. Learn how Cake renders views and just adept the view files to whatever CSS framework you use. You might want to start by reading http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/views.html